# mysql php UPDATE doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1064

I would like to change data from my mysql database ... but it does't work.

Here is the script:

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db('chat',$con);
$uname = $_SESSION['username'];

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET disabled = 'yes' WHERE userame = $uname");

mysql_close($con);

header("Location: logout.php");

?>
```

How can I update the data? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do not use `mysql_* functions because these api is deprcated. Use `mysqli_*` or `pdo`.

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: Unknown column 'userame' in 'where clause'

Comment: Is `userame` a typo? Should column name not be `username` instead?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to put single quotes around your string value:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET disabled = 'yes' WHERE username = '$uname'");
```

FYI, you [shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

You may also be open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174) depending on how you obtain the value conained within `$_SESSION['username']`.

Comment: First thanks for the answer! But it doesn't work :( Whats else might be wrong? I'm trying to get this to work for hours now

Comment: What error do you get? Do you check `mysql_error()`? Have you reviewed the query to make sure it is correct?

Comment: It says "  Unknown column 'userame' in 'where clause'  " :/

Comment: @Intera userame > username missing an "n" in username

Comment: As @E_p has pointed out, you misspelled `username` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET disabled = 'yes' WHERE userame = $uname");
```

To:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `disabled` = 'yes' WHERE `userame` = '$uname'"); // userame might be username.
```

Add the back tacks around the column names because otherwise you could have an error of using a mysql reserved word. Also the quotes around `$uname` are important because otherwise it might not be a string.

Comment: lol .... I'm searching the mistake in the script and it's quite simple... Thank you!!